# How do we connect the redux store to a file that has only an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an array of objects store in a file (menu.js), I want to get the data from `redux` store and update the array file according to data from the store. My file (menu.js) isn't a component. Is there anyway I can connect it to store?

`menu.js` file is as follow:

```
const data = [{

}];
export default data;
```

Comment: Is this menu.js file stored on the server? What's the use case?

Comment: Why not to make it component and use 'useSelector', and 'useDispatch' ?

Comment: @Seth menu.js file has my sidebar's content, such as icons,tags and links. I actually want some of the properties of the content to be dynamically populated from server to my redux and then into my sidebar.

Comment: @DavoMkrtchyan i've never used useSelector or useDispatch, but i will give it a try. do you have any good tutorial for these?

Comment: The official guide is a pretty good one. Here [https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks]

Answer (score 0):

Simply require your menu data where your reducer is defined and seed the `initalState` from there. That reducer will start out with your menu data and, as long as you've configured action cases properly, you can now update that menu data accordingly.

```
import menuItems from "path/to/menu/data";

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  menuItems: menuItems
};

export default function reducer(state = initalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_MENU_ITEM:
      const updateMenuItems = []; // update your items
      return { ...state, menuItems: updatedMenuItems };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data from redux store

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const data = useSelector(store => store.data)
// Get from your store 

// Update store 
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const callSomeFunction  = () =>{
dispatch({
 type: UPDATE_STORE,
 payload: data
});
```

You can find tutorial [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks)